# Admin toolbar not displaying on pages

Tags: admin-bar

The admin bar displays on the dashboard, but does not display on pages or posts.

I'm working with a child theme of Twenty Thirteen that I did not code. I'm a beginning level coder and work mostly with builders. So the builder plugin I installed is also not showing up either.

I've read some potential causes and checked those off. There are things I've tried that did not correct the problem:

The display is set correctly in the user settings.

I logged out as an admin, logged in as a subscriber and logged back in as an admin.

The index.php file contains '' (the code is not displaying, but it is the php call for the footer)

The `function.php` file does not have any code pertaining to the admin bar.

The `footer.php` file does not have any code pertaining to the admin bar.

I do not have access to the client's files on their server, so I cannot use `wp_debug`. I installed a debug plugin, but it runs on the admin bar, which I cannot see, and needs `wp_debug` to be activated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I saw in another thread to add '<?php wp_footer(); ?>' at the end of the footer.php file and that worked! But I still cannot start the builder.

Comment: Check against the many ways you can disable the admin bar - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-disable-the-admin-bar-in-wordpress-3-3--wp-23361

Comment: I asked support for the builder and they suggested I look for the header call since the footer was missing. It was also missing and when I replaced it the admin bar now displays. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check against the many ways you can disable the admin bar - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-disable-the-admin-bar-in-wordpress-3-3--wp-23361

Answer (score 0):

Visibility of admin bar is controlled via the `show_admin_bar()` function. If the child-theme contains this function, and its value is false, then the admin bar will not be shown.

One solution might be to hook into different action hooks with a higher priority, and try to enable the admin bar again:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar', 999);

function remove_admin_bar() {
   show_admin_bar( true );
}
```

You can also try the specific filter on the newer versions, and enable/disable the admin bar:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_true', 999);
```

But the most straight forward solution would be to find and comment out this function in your child-theme.